# I want to design a website that will import a simple 3D Model and engrave a rectangular volume on it as per user values

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I'm very new to web-Dev. Based on my understanding, I am supposed to used Three.JS I think. I'm just not very sure where to start or how to go about doing this.

There will basically be a model.STL file which will be displayed on my webpage, 3 text fields for length, breadth, and height, based on which a cubic volume will be engraved on one side of the STL file when the user hits "generate" and the displayed model will then be updated and it will be available for download.

I have been trying to figure out how to install Three.JS and get started with it. I have previous experiment with CSS and HTML, and some using JS and manipulating 3D Models via Blender, but not in a web scenario.

Answer (score 0):

1. Start of by installing Three.JS, here is the guide https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation. I recommend picking option 2 (CDN), as it's the simplest.
2. Refer to this example on how to load STL files
   https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_stl
   You can click the little button in the bottom right to see it's code
3. Write some code
   Place your STL object in the centre and use an orbit camera
   Use `<object>.scale.x/y/z = <scale>` to edit the scale of the object

I recommend following this tutorial whilst you are doing this https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene